# UIButton pressed for 3 seconds

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a UILabel that contains value "170.00". I now would like to create a button that sets the value to "0" **when it is pressed for 3 seconds**. Obviously, it is easy to change the value of a label with a button, but how can I add the condition that it has to be pressed for at least 3 seconds?

The final result should resemble a "reset" button for a calculator that will reset stored user values when pushed 3 or more seconds.

I don't even know where to begin? NSTimer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, use NSTimer. I'm not going to write the code for you, but you should do the following:

1. When the button is pressed, start the timer
2. When the button is released, end/clear the timer.
3. NSTimer takes a selector to run on an interval. So you can run it after 3 seconds, and if it gets to that method you can change the UILabel text.

Comment: Why not just fire the timer after 3 seconds?

Comment: I was working from memory, I thought maybe the interval was an enum. But you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use a NSTimer for example. When push the button (use the appropriate event for the IBAction), start NSTimer that after 3 seconds do somethings. But when release the button,
you invalidate the timer. So if the button is released before, the timer is stopped.
Otherwise, event is launched and timer invalidate, so when you release the button, timer is already stopped.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this without a timer:

```
-(IBAction)buttonDown:(id)sender {
    [self.label performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"0" afterDelay:3];
}

-(IBAction)buttonUp:(id)sender {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self.label];
}
```

The first method is fired on touchDown, and the second on touch up inside (both connected to the same button). If you lift your finger off the button before the 3 seconds are up, the second method fires and cancels the delayed selector.

Answer (score 1):

Use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method when button press begins. Use `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:` when button is released. This way, you don't need to concern yourself with `NSTimer` (though it may be used by the framework)